# 'Field' is not a member of 'System.Data.DataRow'

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am using VS2005 for vb.net. I am getting compile error at below statement. How to fix this?

```
    For Each rw As DataRow In data.Rows
        For Each dc As DataColumn In stringColumns
            rw.Field(Of String)(dc).Replace("_x00D_", "") //Error showing here
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Update 2:* Up-vote the other more direct/clear answer :-)

---

*Update:* while the following still applies, there *is* a [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) provided by the [DataRowExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class; make sure it is referenced.

---

Because there is no member called `Field` defined over the [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) type... perhaps the special [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx#Y0) property was meant instead?

Note in the example where it is used as an indexer (`row("Name")`). Neat, huh?

(Also, something should be done with the *result* of the `Replace` as strings are immutable in .NET.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 27):

Add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` then your code will work. `Field` is a Extension method you need to add the reference otherwise it will not work.

VS 2005 with .net 2.0 ?

then you can't add reference to this dll. you need to target .net 3.5 or above to use these extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

This error will also occur if you don't explicitly cast the DataRow. *(The original poster does this correctly.)*

Use this:

```
For Each rw As DataRow In data.Rows
```

Not this:

```
For Each rw In data.Rows
```